# Inorder Traversal with return value

Tags: java, scala

So I'm doing inorder traversal for a tree, for which the code goes something like this

```
var traversal:String = ""
def inorder(node: Node): String = {

if (node == null)
  return traversal
inorder(node.leftChild)
traversal += node.label
inorder(node.rightChild)
return traversal
}
```

I'm facing an issue though (a really stupid one) that when I run it for two nodes (say A and B), the value of ***traversal*** obtained while running for A is also included while getting ***traversal*** for B. Since it is a recursive function, I cannot define ***traversal*** inside the function either. Please tell how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, because you are trying to re-assign a `val`. A `val` can only be initialized once and cannot be re-assigned. Also, your code is not very Scala-like, because you are using `null` and `return`.

You should use `Option` instead of `null` for values that can potentially be empty. `null` really only exists for interoperability with Java and should be avoided in pure Scala code.

You do not need to use the `return` keyword; the last expression that's executed in a method is automatically the method's return value.

This would be a better implementation (still using `null` - you'll need to modify your `Node` class to get rid of that):

```
def inorder(node: Node): String =
  if (node == null) ""
  else inorder(node.leftChild) + node.label + inorder(node.rightChild)
```

When using `Option`:

```
case class Node(leftChild: Option[Node], label: String, rightChild: Option[Node])

def inorder(node: Option[Node]): String =
  node map { n => inorder(n.leftChild) + n.label + inorder(n.rightChild) } getOrElse ""
```

Example use:

```
scala> val tree = Node(Some(Node(None, "left", None)), "root", Some(Node(None, "right", None)))
tree: Node = Node(Some(Node(None,left,None)),root,Some(Node(None,right,None)))

scala> inorder(Some(tree))
res2: String = leftrootright
```

Comment: val is written there by mistake. It is var in my code. So I've edited that.

Thanks for the help. And so great of you to provide the extra tips about Scala.

Comment: Also, here you used the concatenation property of string to our advantage. Would writing such a code be possible if someone has to return something else, say a List of Strings (say in some other problem?)

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, you can concatenate lists just as you can concatenate strings. It would be almost the same.